# JPA uses subquery instead of join

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, jpa, criteria

I have an entity that looks like this:

```
@Entity(name = "File")
@Table(name = "files", schema = "myschema")
public class FileEntity implements Serializable {
    
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;
    
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "owner_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private CustomerEntity owner;
    
    @ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @CollectionTable(
            name = "file_customers", //joining table containing customer_id and file_id
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "file_id")
    )
    @Column(name = "customer_id")
    private Set<Long> visibleTo;
}
```

I use this in conjunction with the CriteriaBuilder like so:

```
final CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
final CriteriaQuery<FileEntity> cr = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(FileEntity.class);
final Root<FileEntity> root = cr.from(FileEntity.class);
root.join("owner", JoinType.LEFT).alias("owner");
//add conditions, sort orders, etc...
final TypedQuery<FileEntity> query = entityManager.createQuery(cr);
query.getResultList();
```

Now when I query by the owner field I get this sql:

```
select * from myschema.files as files
left outer join myschema.customer as customer on files.owner_id=customer.id
where customer.name=?
```

But when I query for the visibleTo field, I get a subquery:

```
select * from myschema.files as files
left outer join myschema.customer as customer on files.owner_id=customer.id
where ? in (select visibleTo.customer_id from myschema.file_customers as visibleTo where files.id=visibleTo.file_id)
```

Though the query I'd *like* to get is this:

```
select * from myschema.files as files
left outer join myschema.customer as customer on files.owner_id=customer.id
left outer join myschema.file_customers as visibleTo on files.id=visibleTo.file_id
where visibleTo.id = ?
```

The subquery version is over 2 orders of magnitude slower than the join version in my postgres(10.14) database.

Adding `root.join("visibleTo", JoinType.LEFT).alias("visibleTo");` creates the join that I want, but still uses a subquery in the where clause anyways.
I also thought about using `@ManyToMany` instead of `@ElementCollection`, but that would mean I'd have to unnecessarily load complete objects instead of just the ids.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are using the "member of" predicate which will render this SQL. The SQL you "want" does not include a filter for the customer_id but it appears you actually want this filter since you wrote some kind of code to apply the member of predicate.